# World HDRi map - colors doesn't match?

Tags: rendering, texturing, world, hdri

I've created a custom environment texture (see below) and tried to apply it to the image. For some reason the texture comes out blue. The photo itself is not tinted (daylight-balanced floodlight and white walls), but when imported to blender it looks weird. I've tried a lot of things, including playing with color spaces (no difference) and adding RGBtoBW node (see below) and the environment texture still comes out blue.

What am I missing?

[image: weird tint of the environment texture]

Comment: How exactly did you create the HDRI? Could it be that something went wrong when creating it from the different exposure levels? In what software did you check that it looks correct?

Comment: Have you checked the lights? One might have a blue emission.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visualy screen looks like you have enabled **Use Curves** in sub panel of **Color Management** with some adjustment there.

[image]

BTW When I see missing navigation icons in your screen, there can be graphic card issue ...

Comment: OMG, I feel so stupid. Thanks! That was exactly the problem. I remember playing with that a few days ago (for whatever reason), then switched to modeling and forgot about it.

Comment: You don't have to ;-) We all know that feeling from any complex program. There is always some button we forgot to think about it.